# Why isn't there one merged button ' GIT commit+push' in IDEA2018 of JetBrain?

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, ide, git-commit, git-push

I am searching for a version control button 'Git Commit+Push' in Jetbrain IDEA 2018.
[image]
But there is only a 'Git Push' button, a 'Git Commit' button as they are two separate buttons,but it seems not too convenient because of tedious design in GIT: 'commit' and 'push' are two different steps.

Can anyone tell where it's?

Maybe it's exists but I don't know where it's, or maybe there's not such button in IDEA2018 at all!
There is a one merged button in Eclipse and it's very convenient.[image]

Comment: To avoid pursuing excessive technology, I have taken back to the measure of using SVN for version control  of my java projects in IDEA instead of GIT.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Commit and Push` button in`Commit toolwindow` (Ctrl/Cmd+K)

[image]

**EDIT**:
After additional information it seems that you don't need a push dialog.
If that's the case - please disable "Show push dialog for Commit and push" under File | Settings | Version Control | Git

Comment: No, you doesn't know my requirements @Ruslan, I want to merge 'CTRL+SHIF+K‘ and 'CTRL+K' as one shortcut/button to git commit+push at a sametime.

Comment: What's number of version of IDEA are you using? @Ruslan. is it the version 2023 ? I'm using the 2018 version.

Comment: This is a pretty old version. Would you mind updating to the latest version?

Comment: After additional information it seems that you don't need a push dialog.
If that's the case - please disable "Show push dialog for Commit and push" under File | Settings | Version Control | Git

Comment: I found you are right ->"I don't need a push dialog" :) as I am working on a small project ! Another thing, I tried to turn off the the show of 'push button' with your suggestion, it doesn't take effective on IDEA ! let it be ... Because I've already found how to git commit+push quickly by keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

While there might not be one button, there is a shortcut.
You can use `⌘ ⌥ K` on macOS, or `Ctrl+Alt+K` on Windows/Linux to Commit & Push code. For more information, see [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html).

If you really want this to be a button, you can check in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) whether there is already an issue for that and upvote it, or create a new issue yourself.

Comment: I executed the command 'CTRL+ALT+K' in my IDEA 2018, but no any menu popup! Is this feature only available in the new version?

Comment: @JamesWang Yes, that might be the case. Please upgrade to a newer version as also suggested by Ruslan Kuleshov.

Answer (score 0):

After many times try,I found that the shortcut 'Ctrl+Alt+K' only take effctive after I typed the 'Ctrl+K'. but it's enough convenient for me so far because I don't have to select the 'GIT comit+push' menu by mouse.
[image]